# Android: Get values from interface

Tags: java, android, interface

My Interface

```
public interface TimeGetter {
public void setTime(int hour, int minute);}
```

I have implemented this interface in my `Activity` and got the hour and minute as shown below

```
public void setTime(int hour, int minute){
Log.i("hour",hour);
}
```

Works perfectly fine.

How can I get the value hour and minute inside the `Activity`? I already have it in the interface implementation of the activity.

Comment: You need set something that can trigger that interface.

Comment: @jake I have triggered the interface from another activity. Log.i("hour",hour); works completely fine..

Comment: @AshutoshChapagain yes, but you need to store the values in fields, or an array, or pass them to another class which will store them, for example.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried storing in a class's property. Still I cannot toast it from my onCreate

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by getting values from your interface. Did you create a class that implements the interface and now you want to get the values from that class?

Comment: @LAD i already have the value I need in activity's interface implementation. Now i want it in my Activity.

Comment: @LAD it is Activity

Comment: @Ashutosh Chapagain If you find hack how to get that variable, let me know. I have similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity :

```
    //Use below variables to set values and access them inside your activity    
        private int hour;
        private int minute;


        @Override
        public void setTime(int hour, int minute){
        Log.i("hour",hour);
       //You can use hour minute value here like setting text to textview etc or set them to instance variable for further use

        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        }
```

Comment: Did that. Where can I use hour, minute after that? I tried to use it in onResume() but failed.

Comment: the values will be set once you get callback in your `setTime` then you can use those values in same method for setting text to textview etc. or set them to variables like shown in code to use after some other actions

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an error because you have the wrong argument type for your `Log` call. Instead of this:

```
Log.i("hour", hour);
```

it should be this:

```
Log.i("hour", String.valueOf(hour));
```

This is because `Log` takes a `String` as a parameter, not an `int`.